# Allowed memory size Laravel (unzipping file with Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to unzip big file unzip big dump file and I run into this common problem:

> local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException:
>   Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   123732000 bytes) in /Users/ ...

I know that I can increase memory limit and should work, but I think the problem is in my code and I'm doing something wrong:

```
public function unzip() {
        // unzip file
        // set input and output files
        $out = 'storage/app/dump/auct_lots_full.sql';
        $in = 'storage/app/dump/auct_lots_full.sql.bz2';

        // decompress file using BZIP2
        if (file_exists($in)) {
            $data = '';
            $bz = bzopen($in, 'r') or die('ERROR: Cannot open input file!');
            while (!feof($bz)) {
                $data .= bzread($bz, 4096) or die('ERROR: Cannot read from input file');;
            }
            bzclose($bz);
            file_put_contents($out, $data) or die('ERROR: Cannot write to output file!');
            echo 'Decompression complete.';
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `shell_exec`, with proper security considerations, of course?

Comment: sorry, I miss understood. Can you. show some example?

Comment: `shell_exec('bzip2 -d /path/to/storage/app/dump/auct_lots_full.sql.bz2');`

Comment: great only I need to rewrite file if exists.

Comment: @fubar now the end result should look like this: `shell_exec('bzip2 -d -f /path/to/storage/app/dump/auct_lots_full.sql.bz2');` ???

Comment: You can put the two flags together, e.g. `bzip2 -df /path/to/file.bz2`

Comment: @fubar Thank you so much,  I learn today a super useful command!!!